# Magento 2: how Get youtube video in product list page(Category page)

Tags: magento2, product, video

I want to get product video in product list page(category page) for that i am trying following code . but i am getting blank values. my code is:

```
$_product->getVideo();
```

Please guide me for get you tube video url.

I tried code but that works in product listing page but not worked in product details page.

**Code what i have tried :**

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>`

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this--

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>`

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have also try this . it working fine in detail page but not in list page